# Check if current timestamp matches crontab time pattern in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, cron

Is it possible to check if the current timestamp matches a given time pattern in `crontab` style? Like:

```
if (time_match(time(), "10 * * * *") === true)
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587425/php-function-that-receive-a-cron-string-and-return-the-next-run-timestamp