# How to prevent PHP from doing octal math in conditionals? (why does 08 === 0)

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion, octal

I was working with code that parses crontab.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5727346/3774582

I found it works great, however I found that if I made a cron like

```
0 * * * *
```

It would run at the 0 minute, the 8th minute, and the 9th minute. I broke down every line of the code.

https://gist.github.com/goosehub/7deff7928be04ec99b4292be10b4b7b0

I found that I was getting this conditional for the value of 0 if the current minute was 8.

```
08 === 0
```

I tested this with PHP

```
if (08 === 0) {
    echo 'marco';
}
```

After running that, I saw `marco` on the output. It appears PHP is treating `08` as an octal. Because in octal after `07` is `010`, `08` and `09` is evaluated as `00`.

How can I force a decimal comparison in this conditional?

Comment: Where is `08` coming from?

Comment: Instead of using `date()` to get the fields of the current time, use `getdate()`. This returns an associative array with the time components as numbers, you don't need to parse a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP docs in Integer

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).

However, don't just use `ltrim($time[$k], '0')` because this will turn `0` into . Instead, use a regular expression. In this case, `/^0+(?=\d)/`.

In this case, apply it to the `$time[$k]` input like so.

```
$time[$k] = preg_replace('/^0+(?=\d)/', '', $time[$k]);
```